# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for.net 10.2.7

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Is ArcGIS Runtime SDK  for.net 10.2.7 compatible with 10.5 ArcGIS servers? 
We are in ArcGIS 10.3.1 release and planning to upgrade our ArcGIS Servers to 10.5. Are there any known issues in upgrading the GIS Server to 10.5 and leave the runtime sdk for .net to 10.2.7?